# Javascript can't read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

When running the following code, I am getting the error

> "can't read property 'word' of undefined on the starred.

```js
var arr = [{
    key1: 'value1'
  },
  {
    key1: 'value2'
  }
];
for (var k = 0; k <= arr.length; k++) {
  console.log(arr[k].key1);
}
```

Comment: `k <= arr.length` will cause `arr[2]` which is obviously `undefined`. Try `k < arr.length` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array index range is 0, to arr.length - 1.

```js
var arr = [{
    key1: 'value1'
  },
  {
    key1: 'value2'
  }
];
for (var k = 0; k <= arr.length - 1; k++) {
  console.log(arr[k].key1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For condition `<=`, value of `k` will become `2` for last iteration which is not defined.

Condition should be `k < arr.length` so that value of `k` will be "0...1"

```js
var arr = [{
    key1: 'value1'
  },
  {
    key1: 'value2'
  }
];
for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
  console.log(arr[k].key1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your iteration ends in an empty object, change loop condition from < to <=.

```
var arr = [{
    key1: 'value1'
  },
  {
    key1: 'value2'
  }
];
for (var k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
  console.log(arr[k].key1);
}
```

When you are iterating from 0 to array.length, then you are iterating over array.length+1 elements, so you are asking for one element too much.